# vb.net Delegate and invoke issue

Tags: vb.net

I'm having problems with a program where I've got some multi threaded activities addressing the states of check boxes, which in turn are created by a user definable interface

To achieve this I'm using the code below, which works on some occasions and crashes on other occasions when it stops with the following error

NullReferenceException was unhandled
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Delegate Sub CBSetCallback(ByVal cb As CheckBox, ByVal value As Boolean)



Private Sub SetCheckBox(ByVal cb As CheckBox, ByVal state As Boolean)
    If cb.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New CBSetCallback(AddressOf CBset)
        Invoke(d, New Object() {cb, state})
    Else
        cb.Checked = state
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CBset(ByVal cb As CheckBox, ByVal state As Boolean)
    cb.Checked = state
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example could do with more code around the edges but it looks ok.  Are you sometimes passing in nothing instead of a valid checkbox?

Comment: there is always a valid check box passed when it crashes, I suspect it it has something to do with the main thread making a call to the setcheckbox sub, immediately followed by a second call, because the calls are initiated by the asynchronous thread then is it possible that the main thread is still resolving the first call when the second is made. Ive been looking at a BeginInvoke/endInvoke methodology with the thought that I could use the end invoke to check the original call is complete before making a second